# Check if value exists exactly like that with SQL query (regexp)?

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, eloquent

Example json in the socialMedia database column

```
[{"id":"1463dae5-1168-432e-8e55-c61820d69c49","value":"person2"}, 
{"id":"c61820d69c49-8e55-432e-8e55-8e55","value":"person1"}]
```

I want to run a query to check if "value":"person1" or "value:"person2" or something else like that exists in the json field. Is that possible to do with regexp or something?

Comment: Why regex if you can extract value from json. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/functions-json.html

Also attach postgresql version

Answer (score 0):

Using [JSON_SEARCH](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search)

```php
App\Models\User::whereRaw('JSON_SEARCH(users.name, "all", "%person%")')->get();
```

Or using [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract)

```php
App\Models\User::where(DB::raw('JSON_EXTRACT(`name`, "$.*")'), 'LIKE', '%person%')->get();
```